# htaccess redirect: [everyone] [every page] -> [holding page] - except me?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm about to launch the latest version of my webapp and would like to ensure all visitors are redirected to a holding page while i make the transition.

So i need an htaccess redirect that excludes my ip somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the remove address:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.345.67.89
RewriteRule !^maintanence$ maintanence [L]
```

You also might want to exclude other files like images, stylesheets, etc.:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.345.67.89
RewriteRule !^(maintanence$|images/|style/) maintanence [L]
```

This will rewrite any request that’s URL path is either not `/maintanence` or does start with `/images/` or `/style/`.

Comment: ha, i hadn't thought about excluding the holding page from the rule, that would have been a classic!